# GCP rename files with same name as existing directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to rename my file toto.html by removing its extension using gsutils. My folder/files are organized this way:

```
toto     ----|
             |
             |--file1.html
             |
             |--file2.txt
             |
             |-- ...
             |
toto.html
```

So I used the command :

```
gsutil mv gs://my_bucket/toto.html  gs://my_bucket/toto
```

the problem is by doing so, the file is moved inside the folder that has the same name as the directory. ( which is normal )

How can I rename my file without having this issue?

thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to convert file to directory ?

Comment: No, i’m trying to remove the extension of my file toto.html and the file gets moved inside the directory

Comment: If you plan to use gsutil or the Google Cloud Console GUI in the future, **do not do this**. They have special behavior to **emulate** directories, which do not exist in Cloud Storage. Otherwise, you will need to use an API/SDK to rename the object.

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain briefly about how directories work on Google Cloud Storage, as detailed in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders):

> Cloud Storage operates with a flat namespace, which means that folders don't actually exist within Cloud Storage. If you create an object named `folder1/file.txt` in the bucket your-bucket, the path to the object is `your-bucket/folder1/file.txt`, but there is no folder named `folder1`; instead, the string `folder1` is part of the object's name.

So when you perform the move command `gsutil mv gs://my_bucket/toto.html  gs://my_bucket/toto`, gsutil interprets it like you would like to move the file inside the folder named `toto` as there is no way to differentiate between the file and the folder.

What you could do to achieve the task is move the file inside a folder first to change its name and then get it back to root:

```
gsutil mv gs://my_bucket/toto.html  gs://my_bucket/toto/toto
gsutil mv gs://my_bucket/toto/toto  gs://my_bucket/
```